# How to generate signature using hash string using iTextSharp and c#

Tags: itext, signature

I am trying to add public key string in MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer but having error,

string sing_test = "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";

```
byte[] rawData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(sing_test );

    public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
        {
            using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf))
            {
                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, signatureFieldName);
                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
                MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
                stamper.Close();
                return SHA1Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());
            }
        }
    }

public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
        {
            PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);               
            PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
            sap.Reason = "Testing";
            sap.Location = "Test";
            sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(250, 50, 50, 100), 1, null);
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);
            try
            {
               MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(sap, external, 8192);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {  }
            st.Close();
        }
    }
}

private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    private readonly byte[] signedBytes;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
    {
        this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        return signedBytes;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
    }
}
```

getting error..
Error during signature verification.
Error encountered while BER decoding:

Thanks...

Comment: If I understand your code correctly (you are some taciturn in regard to explanations), you first call `GetBytesToSign` which returns a hash value, then you somehow sign the hash and embed it using `EmbedSignature`. Which parameters do you use when calling those methods? If you use the pdf output of the first method as input of the second (which I assume because of the the names of the parameters of those methods), then you add two distinct signature fields, a first one in which no signature is embedded, and a second one in which the signature generated for the first one is embedded...

Comment: ... or do you use the original PDF file as input for both methods and throw away the output PDF of the first method call? In that case you insert into the signature field there a signature value for a hash generated for a different range which you threw away. Or do you use your code still somehow else?

Comment: And what are you trying to do with that certificate? BTW, the base 64 encoded string appears to be somehow broken.

Comment: Thanks,

I want to apeend digital signature on PDF using public key.

Comment: Please clarify your question; in my three initial comments I asked for clarification of a number of aspects. That been said... *"I want to apeend digital signature on PDF using public key."* - you are aware that you do also need the private key for signing? (Explicitly in case of p12, implicitly in case of a HSM or a signing service.)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mkl for your response. I would like to add signature using PKCS#7 file to the PDF. However, PKCS#7 doesn't hold any private key but it holds the public key. Using this public key I would like to sign the document. Is it possible to sign the PDF without private key (Using only public key)??? If Yes, then how can we stamp signature object with PDF without making PDF invalid. In short using PKCS#7, I am self signing the PDF document . Thanks in advance for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Obviously it is not possible to sign with the public key alone; otherwise anyone could sign in your name, your public key is *public* after all. Thus, you do need a private key. Furthermore, the private key obviously will not be included in the PKCS#7 container (because then it would not be *private* anymore) but it is *used* to calculate the signature value. As you only need to use the private key to calculate a signature value, the key itself might be boxed externally, e.g. some smart card, some USB token, a HSM, or a signing service, with some option to request a signature value from it.

Comment: That been said, please first download the iText white paper ["Digital Signatures for PDF Documents"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books#digsig) and use it with the updated example code [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper) (.Net ports of the codes are linked to at the bottom of each example). If after studying that you still have questions on details, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mkl for in-depth information. As per your last comments, we can not sign using public key and also it is logically correct. Can we simple make visible signature and add stamper object in pdf? In short if I want to just add public key details on stamper object at visible signature in PDF using itext. Is it possible? If yes then how can we make it visible without making PDF invalid.

Comment: *"I want to just add public key details on stamper object at visible signature in PDF using itext"* - First of all I assume you don't ask in the context of signing anymore because for that context everything is explained in the referenced white paper. So, you can of course stamp any text or image onto a PDF using iText, so in particular something with the looks of a signature with certificate details. The behavior, in particular in signature-aware viewers like Adobe Reader, differs, of course.